# React architecture for a news feed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am building a react-native app involving a news feed view. The app is built such that all feed items cover the entire page and the user swipes up/down to view next/previous item.

The issue I am running into is around adding new items into the mix. In case of rapid swiping of items, if I try to insert new content into the item queue, causing a re-render, there is either a lag in swipe or a swipe that just hangs in there.

Is there a way I can tell react to just add those items after the current item queue without triggering a re-render?

Comment: if you want the new items to be visible, then it has to re-render

Comment: can you show the render parts and your data handling?

Comment: could you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

Return false in [componentShouldUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate)() method.